# How to get UTC timestamps from JDBC+postgreSql timestamp?

Tags: java, postgresql, datetime, jdbc

I created a table like like this in PostgreSQL:

```sql
create table myTable (
    dateAdded timestamp(0) without time zone null default (current_timestamp at time zone 'UTC');
)
```

I choose "without time zone" because I know that all timestamps that my application works with are *always* UTC. As far as I got the documentation the only difference to "with timestamp" is that I can supply values in other time zones which will then be converted to UTC. However I want to avoid such automatic conversions because they could hardly do any good if I know that my values are UTC.

When I add a new record in my test table and view the table's content with pgAdmin I can see that the insertion date has been correctly saved in UTC format.

However when I try to select values using JDBC the value gets 2 hours subtracted. I am located at UTC+2, so it looks like that JDBC assumes that the date in the table is not a UTC timestamp, but a UTC+2 timestamp instead and tries to convert to UTC.

Some googling revealed that the JDBC standard dictates something about conversion to/from the current time zone, but that this could be prevented by supplying a Calander to getTimestamp/setTimestamp calls. However supplying a calendar did not make any difference at all. Here is my MyBatis/Jodatime converter:

```java
@MappedTypes(DateTime.class)
public class DateTimeTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<DateTime> {
    private static final Calendar UTC_CALENDAR = Calendar.getInstance(DateTimeZone.UTC.toTimeZone());

    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i,
            DateTime parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        ps.setTimestamp(i, new Timestamp(parameter.getMillis()), UTC_CALENDAR);
    }

    @Override
    public DateTime getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName)
            throws SQLException {
        return fromSQLTimestamp(rs.getTimestamp(columnName, UTC_CALENDAR));
    }
    /* further get methods with pretty much same content as above */

    private static DateTime fromSQLTimestamp(final Timestamp ts) {
        if (ts == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new DateTime(ts.getTime(), DateTimeZone.UTC);
    }
}
```

What's the correct way to get UTC timestamps from JDBC+PostgreSQL timestamp source?

Comment: Have you considered using the new java 8 time api?, The dateTime class used to have this kind of problems. Maybe using Instant class from java 8 instead of DateTime.

Answer (score 24):

### Solution

Set UTC as default timezone of your JVM `-Duser.timezone=UTC` or set your whole OS to UTC.

### Background

In Postgres both `TIMESTAMP` and `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` are stored the same way - number of seconds since Postgres epoch (2000-01-01). The main difference is what Postgres do when it saves timestamp value such as `2004-10-19 10:23:54+02`:

- without TZ the `+02` is just stripped away
- with TZ a `-02` correction is performed to make it UTC

Now the interesting thing is when JDBC driver loads the value:

- without TZ the stored value is shifted by the user's (JVM / OS) TZ
- with TZ the value is considered to be UTC

In both cases you will end up with `java.sql.Timestamp` object with user's default TZ.

### Time Zones

Timestamps without TZ are pretty limited. If you have two systems connected to your database, both with different TZ, they will interpret timestamps differently. Therefore, I strongly advice you to use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`.

---

### Update

You can [tell JDBC](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/c0192e8417373e3ca2eb9157af0716de3b304062/org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java#L516) what kind of TZ it should use when reading timestamp via [`ResultSet#getTimestamp(String, Calendar)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Calendar%29). Excerpt from JavaDoc:

> This method uses the given calendar to construct an appropriate millisecond value for the timestamp if the underlying database does not store timezone information.

Comment: certainly a valid answer but, requires having system access. I'd prefer a solution which allows me to ship a war file which can be deployed on servers without such server configuration issues.

Comment: Updated answer with information how to make JDBC driver use different TZ. You are mentioning something similiar in your question, but you might have just used different method.

Comment: Using the `-Duser.timezone=UTC` trick, DB queries parameters are now being sent in UTC (good), but the results are still time shifted to local timezone.  Changing the client system clock is my current work around.  Is there a JDBC parameter or JVM parameter to disable this conversion? (ie something like your `getTimestamp()` solution, but not in Java code.  I only have access to compiled JAR (PyCharm, which uses JDBC).

Comment: Where the time shifting occurs? You mean that you get incorrect time in the `ResultSet` directly from JDBC when running with `-Duser.timezone=UTC`?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few tricks specific for the Postgres JDBC driver

See https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/java8-date-time.html

So when reading you can do

```
    Instant utc =resultSet.getObject("dateAdded",LocalDateTime.class).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

If you use a connection pool such as Hikari, you can also specify the time time-zone used by each connection by setting *connectionInitSql*=**set time zone 'UTC'**

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by Pavel (adding the jvm param '-Duser.timezone=UTC') is for sure the best option, if you don't have system access, this isn't always possible to do.

The only way I found is to convert the timestamp to [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) in the query and read it as a `long`.

```
SELECT  extract(epoch from my_timestamp_colum at time zone 'utc')::bigint * 1000 
            AS my_timestamp_as_epoc
FROM    my_table
```

Then read it in plain JDBC with

```
ResultSet rs = ...
long myTimestampAsEpoc = rs.getLong("my_timestamp_as_epoc");
Date myTimestamp = new Date(myTimestampAsEpoc);
```

With iBatis/MyBatis, you need to handle the column as a Long, then convert it manually to Date/Timestamp. Inconvenient and ugly.

The reverse operation in PostgreSQL can be done with:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE 'epoch' + 
       1421855729000 * INTERVAL '1 millisecond'
```

That said, the JDBC specification doesn't say that the returned timestamp shall or shall not shift the timestamp to the user time zone; BUT since you defined the table column as 'timestamp without time zone' I would expect no time shifts, but the recorded epoch being just wrapped in a `java.sql.Timestamp`. For my opinion, this is a bug in the PostgreSQL JDBC driver. Being the problem at this level, then, probably there is not much more that can be done, without system access.

Comment: The JDBC specification (or: the API documentation) requires that - by default - time is considered in the current timezone of the JVM. If you want to use another timezone, then you can provide a `Calendar` in the right timezone. As this is what is done in the question, it looks like that is the actual bug.

Comment: Can you please point out where the JDBC spec states the JVM timezone as default?  I searched yesterday, and I didn't find it.

Comment: See the documentation of [`PreparedStatement.setTimestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp-int-java.sql.Timestamp-java.util.Calendar-) and [`ResultSet.getTimestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp-int-java.util.Calendar-)

Comment: See [`setTimestamp(int parameterIndex, Timestamp x)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp-int-java.sql.Timestamp-): it doesn't mention any calendar or time zone at all. The fact that this method delegates to [`setTimestamp(int parameterIndex, Timestamp x, Calendar cal)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp-int-java.sql.Timestamp-java.util.Calendar-) with a `null` calendar it's an implementation detail that is not mandated by the spec.

Comment: Also, notice that the question mention the column type as 'timestamp without time zone'; so I would expect to get back a timestamp without time zone when I read it from the db (at least, by default). Basically, if you read the timestamp from the db then you write it back to the db AS-IS, you actually shift it... not nice.

Comment: Emphasis mine: _"If **no Calendar object** is specified, the driver uses the **default timezone**, which is that of the virtual machine running the application."_ The problem with JDBC is that you need to juggle the spec, the API doc, and keep in mind that information is not always repeated. The set/getTimestamp without Calendar is the case mentioned here as _"If no Calendar object is specified"_

Comment: That is not how JDBC works unfortunately. Upto JDBC 4.2, JDBC didn't even have 'with timezone' support. And as pre-JSR-310 (`java.time`) Java always needed a timezone for time interpretation, knowing which timezone to use (and using a 'reasonable' default) is simply a necessity.